# Does rxjs timeout auto unsubsribe

Tags: rxjs, nestjs

On nestjs, I'm using `cache` on observable to reduce call to firestore. I used observable to listen to realtime changes on the firestore. On a page, there's call to multiple API endpoints, thus I want to reduce the number of times read from the same document on firestore. I want to maintain the observable until there's no call to the document after certain period of time (10 minutes).

Tested using cache-manager to store the observable and it does work but I am wondering, when timeout is triggered, does it closed the subscription (unsubscribe). From my test, it doesn't seems to unsubscribe. This would lead to memory leak if that's the case right? Is there anyway to unsubscribe from the timeout? I tried triggering a subject and use `takeUntil`. How can I confirm the the subscriptions are unsubscribe?

```
let observable: Observable<DocumentSnapshot<T>> = await this.cacheManager.get(key);
    
    if(!observable) {
      const subject = new Subject<void>();

      observable = new Observable<DocumentSnapshot<T>>(obs => {
        doc.onSnapshot(snapshot => obs.next(snapshot));
      }).pipe(
        timeout({
          each: 5000,
          with: () => {
            this.cacheManager.del(key);
            subject.next();
            throw new Error('Timeout');
          }
        }),
        shareReplay(1),
        takeUntil(subject),
      );

      await this.cacheManager.set(key, observable);
    }

return observable;
```

Answer (score 1):

> when timeout is triggered, does it closed the subscription (unsubscribe)

Nope. The `timeout` inside the pipe works for every emission separately, not for the entire stream. I think `timer` with `takeUntil` would serve your purpose, like this:

```
const source = timer(0, 1000);
const stop = timer(5000);

source.pipe(takeUntil(stop)).subscribe(console.log);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-gpc6zk?devtoolsheight=100&file=index.ts

Comment: This does works. But I want to maintain the subscription in the cache as long as there's request to the observable.